# StreamCorruptedException when de-serializing through ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to test a program and for that I need to access ReadExternal function but I am getting StreamCorrupted exception on ObjectInputStream. 
I know I need to use the object written by WriteObject but dont know how to do it...

```
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
    out.writeObject(ss3); 
    ss3.writeExternal(out);
    try{
         ByteInputStream bi=new ByteInputStream();
         bi.setBuf(bb);
         out.write(bb);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bb));
         String s1=(String) in.readObject();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple, self contained example of what you are trying to do?  You shouldn't be calling read/writeExternal directly as these are used by the Object Stream.

Comment: What is `bb` here? As Peter says, a short but complete program would really help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, you are trying to write the same object twice to the output stream:

```
out.writeObject(ss3); 
ss3.writeExternal(out); // <-- Remove this!
```

The second write makes wrong use of the `writeExternal()` method, which should never be called explicitly but will be called by the `ObjectOutputStream`.

And: `out.write(bb);` tries to write the content of `bb` to the `ObjectOutputStream`. That's probably not what you want.

Try it like this:

```
// Create a buffer for the data generated:
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream( bos );

out.writeObject(ss3);

// This makes sure the stream is written completely ('flushed'):
out.close();

// Retrieve the raw data written through the ObjectOutputStream:
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

// Wrap the raw data in an ObjectInputStream to read from:
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream( data );
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( bis );

// Read object(s) re-created from the raw data:
SomeClass obj = (SomeClass) in.readObject();

assert obj.equals( ss3 ); // optional ;-)
```

Comment: I was just not trying to close the/flush the out and needed to convert the wrote object to ByteArray
Thanks a lot....:-)

Comment: I had the same problem. I wasn't calling `writeExternal`, but I wasn't calling `out.close()` either. Adding `out.close()` fixed it. Thank you for saving my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

> ss3.writeExternal(out);

You shouldn't be calling that method directly. You should be calling

```
out.writeObject(ss3);
```